# How to un-extrude an object?

Tags: extrude

[image: Screenshot]
I was making a cup handle so I extruded a face of the cup, then however I right clicked and thought that would undo it. I didn't notice the dent it left though, after that I did a bunch of smoothing on the cup and then when I went back to extrude it, it didn't create the smoothing I wanted. That's when I noticed the dent, I decided to make the handle on a different face, but is there any way I can remove the ugly dent?

P.S I am a beginner so please don't be angry with me for thinking right click was undo.

P.P.S Cup is on layer 2.

[image]

Comment: As the subsurface modifier is set to 3, probably there are few vertices to rework?

Comment: Depending on the case there might be several ways to undo. If you didn't move extruded vertices then W > Remove Doubles will suffice (Edit mode > all selected). Otherwise dissolving (X > Dissolve faces, face selected) should be fine

Comment: Sorry for my bad knowledge of blender, but if when I attempt to remove doubles, the face is simply split in half. While if I attempt to dissolve faces, nothing seems to happen

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191734/how-to-return-extrude-back-to-original

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have extruded several times but did not moved the extruded vertices.

In this particular case, to remove that:

- Select the top extruded face (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> then choose 'face' and right click to select the face)
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad+</kbd> to extend the selection. Do that several times. You know you are ok when the selection come to the surrounding parts, when it is deselect twice using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad-</kbd>
- <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the selected vertices
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> then choose 'edge' this time
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the edges surrounding the hole
- <kbd>F</kbd> to remake the face

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it may seem that <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> cancels an operation (as seen with translate, rotate or scale <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) this behaviour appears unpredictable.

After the extrude operation, Blender immedeately goes into the translate operation (usually <kbd>G</kbd>). <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>canceling the operation simply cancels the translate part, snapping the extrude face to where it started from. In vertice mode the result can't be distinguished, since the vertices overlap. In face mode, the additional faces can be seen.

[image]

1. Select the face and delete <kbd>X</kbd> the vertices. Select the remaining vertices and create a new face (<kbd>F</kbd>).
   [image]

**OR**

2. Select the vertices in question or all for that matter (<kbd>A</kbd>) and Remove Doubles. Press <kbd>W</kbd> to open up the specials menu and choose *Remove Doubles*.
   [image]

Comment: For the first one I seem to end up with the same dent as before, for the 2nd one, removing the doubles puts a diagonal line through the dented square.

Comment: @Miroslav Upload a screenshot of that diagonal line to imgur.com and link it here. Or [upload your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Uploaded the file.

Answer (score 1):

In edit-mode: goto Mesh (at the top of the 3D viewport) > Cleanup > Merge by distance. (I know it's an old question but it might help others coming here via google-search).

Comment: you might want to mention that this is just for 2.8, it had a different path in older versions.

Answer (score -1):

I found that selecting some of the affected area (or all of the mesh) and going Mesh>Cleanup>Merge by distance fixed my unnecessary edges from extrusions or otherwise.
The nice thing is that you can do the cleanup to just the affected area in case there are some parts of the mesh that you dont want to merge edges for... for whatever reason...

Answer (score -2):

For un extruding use CTRL+Z incase you do it mistakenly. If that doesn't work select extruded face and delete all of vertices. This will remove the extra part of the mesh.
PS- Right click doesn't work for un extruding so avoid it in the future.