# How to recover extrude back to original?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

[image: cup]

[image]

It seems the surface was extruded by mistake, How can i recover it?
I tried the other answers, but it didn't work.

[image]

merged according to @lemon comment, it seems these four vertices are merged, because the lines around there are twist.

[image]

I deleted these faces and press F to generate new face according to the other answer [How to un-extrude an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107344/how-to-un-extrude-an-object?noredirect=1&lq=1), then it perfectly recovered to original face, thanks all.

Comment: it seems you have not moved it... so select it and the elements around (or select all) and merge by distance

Comment: @lemon, thanks to your comment, I  selected all and merged by distance according to your comment, it seems these four vertices are attached, because the lines around there are twist.